# Were International Students discouraged from applying to the US this year?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, international-students

This is out of curiously - were there many international applicants were planning to apply to the US this past admissions cycle but chose not to because of the current administration/political climate?

Comment: I suggest to change the title so this question does not look like a poll.

Comment: Or could it be the length or teaching style of the courses compared to other places ..

Answer (score 3):

Here're a couple of studies on this issue: [One](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2018/01/22/nsf-report-documents-declines-international-enrollments-after-years-growth), [Two](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2018/01/30/council-graduate-schools-survey-finds-declines-international-applications-new).

There was a small decline - about 1-5% - in both applications and enrollment. This comes after years of growth. Whether the decline is because of the US's political climate though remains unanswered. Possibly - but it could also be a statistical blip.

For comparison, we also have [record numbers of international applicants to UK universities in spite of Brexit](https://qz.com/1198203/despite-brexit-a-record-number-of-foreign-students-want-to-study-at-uk-universities/).